# Tabular Editor 2 - Export measures in unicode file

Tags: tabular

I am exporting all measures & columns using advanced scripting in tabular editor.
It works, but some names are not correct due to Unicode characters that are not saved correctly,

```
var csvMeasures = ExportProperties(Model.AllMeasures,"Name,Description);
SaveFile("c:\\temp\\TabularMeasures.csv", csvMeasures);
```

Any way to keek the Unicode chars that are inside the model?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script to retain unicode characters in the output:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

var csvMeasures = ExportProperties(Model.AllMeasures,"Name,Description");
File.WriteAllText("c:\\temp\\TabularMeasures.csv", csvMeasures, Encoding.Unicode);
```